# Xilinx Virtex5 Simple I/O

Tags: io, microcontroller, xilinx, ttl

I'm using a Virtex 5 FPGA and want to have a few +5/0 I/O pins to communicate with a microcontroller. The only peripherials I've used on the board so far are pushbuttons and switches and no one I've asked seems to know the simplest way to do this I/O. I've looked around the board specification but haven't found any simple way of doing it. I would appreciate any advice you might have.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy thing to do. If you don't have the schematic of the board, then you need to get volt meter with some fine pitch probes and reverse engineer the board.

It is pretty easy if you have 2 boards, with one board it can be really hard since the BGA signals may not be connected to a via and therefore not available on the bottom of the board, and even if they are, then you don't know exactly which pin they are connected to. But with some luck, you can find them since the VIA can only be connected to 4 possible pins surrounding it!

The first thing you need to do is to identify your chip, find the BGA print of the IC from Xilin'x web site.

If your board has some buttons already, then if you are lucky, those signals may be routed to the pins of the FPGA that are available on the bottom of your board. Here are the things you need to do:

- Make sure you have good ESD protection to perform these test
- Put your voltmeter into 'buzzer' mode
- Check the pins of your connector and find out how it is connected, see if there is a pull-up and/or pull-down resistors on the board
- when you find the 'active' pin of your connector, start connecting the other probe to the VIAs one by one
- When you hear a buzz, make a note of the position (guess or measure the distance between the side of t he IC and the location of the via)
- Identify the 4 possible pins that the signal can be connected to
- Write a code to get all those 4 signals and connect them to ChipScope
- In Chip Scope, capture all 4 signals and see which one is the one with the right connection!

alternative, you can create a design with inputs only, capture all the inputs and put them into a memory block and create a  trigger logic to capture all the signals whenever any of the inputs changes, after lots of work and analysis, you will find the correct pins.

Anyway, these are just crazy ideas since this is a really difficult thing to do without having the PCB info of the board.

Good luck with your hacking.